# Rails and SASS: Multiple Color Themes Using Same Variables - Allow user to select preferred theme for account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, themes

I would like to use one set of SASS variables for a Light Theme and change those same SASS variables for my Dark Theme. I do not really want my CSS full of mixins and if statements for each theme, which seem to be most of the answers I found so far. My css is almost entirely written already so I also do not want to go back through and change a ton if possible.

I also would like to give my users the ability to select the theme they wanted and save their preference.

Comment: Heya, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you are sharing your solution - it'll really help other people that have the same issue... but could you possibly edit your question so that it remains a question... and put your solution into an answer instead? You are totally able to answer your own question, and you can even select and "accept" your own answer too. Doing this will help keep things clear for people what the problem was and also it'll make it obvious (when people are searching) that there is definitely a solution. Cheers.

Comment: Ah sorry, thank you! I read that I was able to answer my own questions, I thought it would be practical to do it in the post but I understand that's just not how it's done here so I appreciate your info!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you figured out your problem! thanks for sharing :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to be working well. I can see this method maybe not being practical if you have a bunch of themes that are very large, since it precompiles each theme out. However, I found this to be a great solution for my project. If anyone spots any potential issues I would love to hear them, as I am still a little new to some of this and do not want to break rails rules...

My stylesheets folder looks something like this:
**app/assets/stylesheets/**

> _forms.scss
>   _layout.scss
>   _manifest.scss
>   _mixins.scss
>   _tables.scss
>   _utilities.scss
>   light_theme.scss
>   dark_theme.scss

I have all my components separated out into partials for organization. The "_manifest.scss" file imports all of my components for my themes.

**app/assets/stylesheets/_manifest.scss**

```
// ---------------- Import all CSS components ----------------
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'utilities';
@import 'layout';
@import 'tables';
@import 'forms';
```

I make an .scss file for each theme with the color variables at the top THEN import the manifest. Note, use the same variable names so it swaps out easily.

**app/assets/stylesheets/light_theme.scss**

```
// ---------------- LIGHT THEME ----------------
// Theme Colors
$light: #f4f3ef;
$medium: #9a9a9a;
$dark: #252422;
$ocean: #36414f;
$accent: cadetblue;
$red: #ed4033;
$orange: #ff8c65;
$yellow: #f4ba58;
$green: #76c29d;
$blue: #65b4c6;

// Import all components
@import 'manifest';
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/dark_theme.scss**

```
// ---------------- DARK THEME ----------------
// Theme Colors
$light: #d5d6fa;
$medium: #9e9ed6;
$dark: #0d1118;
$ocean: #1f2c44;
$accent: #806df3;
$red: #f24e77;
$orange: #f2a23b;
$yellow: #f2c54a;
$green: #34d07e;
$blue: #2c8fef;

// Import all components
@import 'manifest';
```

I am using bootstrap for my CSS framework, so most of my color-specific css is set through classes like "btn-blue" "text-orange". This way I have less code to sift through and change when I want to switch themes. The text-orange will still be orange, just a brighter orange on the dark theme vs. a pastel orange on the light theme, which is why the simple variable swap was so necessary.

Some elements need specifically called out, so I use a body class for each theme as well. This lets you make theme-specific changes.
**app/assets/stylesheets/_layout.scss**

```
body.light_theme {
    background-color: $light;
    color: $dark;
}

body.dark_theme {
    background-color: $lake;
    color: $white;
}
```

Next I wanted my user to be able to set their own theme. I created a migration that added a column to my Users table:

```
class AddThemeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :user_theme, :string
  end
end
```

On my Users form, they can select their theme via a dropdown. Your select options are important here because the name turns into the variable, so keep naming consistent.
**app/views/users/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :user_theme, 'Theme' %>
  <%= form.select :user_theme, ['Light Theme', 'Dark Theme'], class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

Now I set my theme in the application controller. If a user is logged in, it takes their theme setting, otherwise it defaults to Light Theme. If you are adding user_theme row to an **existing** users table, make sure you run a migration to set a default theme on every user before adding the below or you will get an error because that cell is empty. Or add some code to check if current_user.user_theme is empty then default to another theme. (Probably better...)
**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_action :set_theme

private
def set_theme
  if current_user
    @user_theme = current_user.user_theme.parameterize.underscore
  else
    @user_theme = 'light_theme'
  end
end

end
```

In the layout file I add the theme to the body as a class:
**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** (layout file)

```
<body class="<%= @user_theme %>">
    ...
</body>
```

You may run into another issue, if you get an asset compile error, add this to your **config/intitializers/assets.rb** one for each theme file.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( dark_theme.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( light_theme.css )
```

Answer (score 0):

So there seems to be an easier way these days:

Stylesheets folder looks something like this:
**app/javascript/stylesheets/**

> application.scss
> light_theme.scss
> dark_theme.scss

Next, add prefers-color-scheme to the application.scss to do all the work for you based on what the user's system preferences are (settings in Windows, MacOS, iOS, Linux, Andriod)

**app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss**

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    @import 'light_theme';
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    @import 'dark_theme';
}
```

Now add the theme preferences in your separate theme files:

**app/javascript/stylesheets/light_theme.scss**

```
background-color: white;
color: black;
```

**app/javascript/stylesheets/dark_theme.scss**

```
background-color: black;
color: white;
```

So, that's it, prefers-color-scheme did all the heavy lifting, no need to save anything in a database as a preference, since multiple users might use the same account and would want different settings.